# 30 amp RV to 50 amp Receptical

Tags: wiring

30 amp RV, 50 amp Receptical. Does it matter which "hot" hole in receptical is used? Can the neutral wire be wired into ground bus bar along with the ground?

Comment: Are we talking plugging the RV into the 50A receptacle?  What type of plug is on the RV, and what type of receptacle is it? (If you can't figure out, we can help given clear photos)

Comment: The plug from the trailer is a 3 pronged 30 amp plug. I got an adapter to allow it to plug into the 4 hole 50 amp receptical.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the plug then please (blades facing the camera)?

Comment: "3 prong 30 amp" doesn't exactly narrow it down.  Post a photo.  Also, doing this wrong could fry or burn down your RV, something I don't say lightly (I'm not known as an alarmist).

Comment: @Robert there are lots of plugs 30amp 3 prong - a photo helps us to identify the style of the plug and receptacle which will give an  indication of voltage and amperage and wiring for proper connection. Your plug or receptacle might even have a NEMA specification on it.

Comment: We are particularly concerned with NEMA 10-30 vs TT30. Adapting a TT30 into a 14-50 must be done *carefully*...

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial adapters available to allow plugging a 30A RV into a 50A receptacle.  It shouldn't matter which hot leg you get, as long as you have the neutral and ground correct.  Both legs of the 50A are rated for 50A **each**, so a 30A max draw is well within capacity.

Comment: I agree the standard 50 a 240v outlet is commonly converted to a 30a 120v plug , similarly that a 30 amp 120v is adapted to a 15 or 20 amp plug. The only concern adapting a 50 to 30 is the wire size for the cord is not rated for 50 amps if there is an electrical failure the cord may melt, or even catch fire. Not a problem with the 30 going down to a 20.

Comment: @Ed Beal, that's a fair point. I assume the adapter has to use wire rated for 50A. To be safe, there should be a fuse or breaker on the adapter, but I've never seen that done. Perhaps the theory is that the protection at the RV distribution box is sufficient?